# Copying PowerPoints Notes Pane to Word Gives Inconsistent Font Sizes

Tags: ms-word, vsto, powerpoint

I have a Word VSTO addin which copies the Notes page for each slide in a PowerPoint file into a Word document.  There are only certain lines in the Notes pane that I need.  My code loops thru each slide, looks for any notes, then checks for the tags and copies the text between the start and end tags.  It is important to maintain the formatting in the Notes page.  However, when pasting into Word, the font copies over, but the size changes.  For instance, the font in PowerPoint might be Times New Roman 12, but in Word it will sometimes randomly change to Times New Roman 14.  It appears that even if pasting a single range of text, the font may change between paragraphs.  Also, certain blocks of text in Word will have the Normal style, but others will have Normal (Web), which affects line spacing.

I tried using a method to retain original source formatting (commented out below), but that sometimes will create bullets before the text, besides changing the font size.

Anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

The abbreviated example code is below.

```
Dim notesRng, fndRng, endRng, copyRng as PowerPoint.TextRange
dim iStart, charLen as Integer

For i As Integer = 0 To pwrPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count - 1
  oSlide = pwrPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
  If oSlide.NotesPage.Shapes.Placeholders(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text.Length > 0 Then
    notesRng = oSlide.NotesPage.Shapes.Placeholders(2).TextFrame.TextRange
    fndRange = notesRng.Find(FindWhat:="START:")
    If Not fndRange is Nothing then
      iStart = notesRng.Text.IndexOf("START:") + 6  ' puts the start just after the colon:
      endRng = notesRng.Find(FindWhat:="END:", After:=iStart)
      If Not endRng is Nothing Then
        charLen = notesRng.Text.IndexOf("END:", iStart) - iStart
        copyRng = oSlide.NotesPage.Shapes.Placeholder(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(iStart, charLen)
        If Not copyRng is Nothing then
          copyRng.Copy
          ThisAddIn.WordApp.Selection.Paste()
          'ThisAddIn.WordApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat(Word.WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting) 
          ThisAddin.WordApp.Selection.Collapse()
        End If
      End If
    End If
  End If
Next I
```

Comment: I'm not a VSTO guy, but if you can substitute a PasteSpecial method for Paste and set the format to unformatted text, that should eliminate the differences.Then the Normal style should format all text.

Comment: I gave this a try but ThisAddIn.WordApp.Selection.PasteSpecial(DataType:=Word.WdPasteDataType.wdPasteText) gives the exception "The specified data type is unavailable."  I tried wdPasteRTF but that changes some math type fonts into WingDings.

Comment: A couple of things aren't clear: 1) What formatting needs to be retained? 2) Is what's being copied more than one line (paragraph - IOW has ENTER been pressed). From what I see, the formatting coming over from PPT is stored in the "paragraph mark". If that's cut off, just plain text comes across and the content adapts Word's `Normal` style. If the paragraph mark is included and source formatting is retained, that's when you get `Normal (Web)`.

Comment: @CindyMeister Re: formatting, I just need the font sizes and line spacing to be consistent.  It does appear that a block of text including a CrLf will cause the leading line to be in Normal (Web) style, whereas the trailing paragraph will be in Normal. I may be able to adapt my code to use that.

Comment: Worst comes to worst you can always either 1) apply formatting directly; 2) forceably remove direct formatting (as opposed to style formatting; 3) apply a specific style (might need to be in combination with 2)